# When trying to slice a pandas dataframe it raises "ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')"

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby, grid-search

I have a huge pandas dataframe called df with the columns "Features","k","r2. The last two columns all contain numbers and the first row contains strings of lists(e.g "[Preop SC, Preop CC]").
I would like to slice the dataframe into smaller dataframes. One dataframe for every "Features"-"k" combination, using nested loops.

Unfortunately it throws up `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare`.

I've tried different slicing methods to produce z: `df[df["Features"]==feat]` and `df.iloc` too. Since when I print features, ["Preop SC","Preop CC"] shows up instead of the quoatation-mark-free version as noted below. I've also tried removing them by converting the entire item to a string, to use the .replace method, but to no avail.
Nothing seems to help me slice with Features. (It works with k alone)

EDIT: Groupby doesn't seem to work either, though I'm a novice at that too
Here is the code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    features=[['Preop SC', 'Preop CC'], ['Preop CC', 'Postoptag'], ['Preop CC', 
    'Pachy'], ['Preop CC', 'K2']]
    df=[]
    count=1
    execute=1
    while execute<3:
        for i in features:
            r2=np.random.normal()
            df.append([i,count,r2])
            count+=1
        execute+=1
        count=1
    df=pd.DataFrame(df)
    df.columns=["Features","KNeighbors","r2 score"]

    summary=[]                                      #Mean of results by feature-k combination
    for feat in features:
        for k in range(1,5):
            temp=o.loc[(o["Features"]==feat)&(o["KNeighbors"]==k):,]
            summary.append([feat,k,temp["r2 score"].mean()])
    summary=pd.Dataframe(summary)
    print(summary)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This is what df looks like:
                Features  KNeighbors  r2 score
0   [Preop SC, Preop CC]           1  0.880299
1  [Preop CC, Postoptag]           2  0.681024
2      [Preop CC, Pachy]           3 -1.925969
3         [Preop CC, K2]           4  1.132059
4   [Preop SC, Preop CC]           1  0.397732
5  [Preop CC, Postoptag]           2 -0.969017
6      [Preop CC, Pachy]           3 -0.173293
7         [Preop CC, K2]           4  0.277422

this is what summary should look like

0   [Preop SC, Preop CC]           1 0.6390155
1  [Preop CC, Postoptag]           2 -0.1439965 
2      [Preop CC, Pachy]           3 -1.049631
3         [Preop CC, K2]           4  0.7047405

Any tips will be dearly appreciated
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Transforming the lists to string using the .apply method allows you to use .groupby:

```
df["Features"]=df.Features.apply(str)
summary=df.groupby("Features").mean()
print(summary)
```